# How to convert a java Date to a ReadableInstant for Joda Time inside a JSP?

Tags: java, jsp, date, jodatime

I instantiated a `java.util.Date` object called `myDate` in my `controller` and passed it to my JSP where I have a Joda Time JSP tag configured with this at the top of the page:

```
<%@taglib prefix="joda" uri="http://www.joda.org/joda/time/tags" %>
```

and of course the necessary `Maven` dependencies added to the project via the POM file.

However, when I try to access `myDate` from the JSP like this:

```
<joda:format value="${myDate}" style="SM" />
```

I get this error:

```
javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: 
value attribute of format tag must be a 
ReadableInstant or ReadablePartial, was: java.util.Date
```

Referring to the [documentation for the Joda Time JSP tags](http://www.joda.org/joda-time-jsptags/userguide.html), I can't tell how I should 'convert' my `myDate` to a `ReadableInstant` or `ReadablePartial` in the context of this JSP?

Comment: Please don't confuse 3rd party taglibs with [JSTL](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info). I removed the JSTL tag from the question.

Answer (score 18):

The error message is self-explaining. The JodaTime tags doesn't accept a Java SE standard `Date` instance, but a JodaTime [`DateTime`](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTime.html) instance or whatever implements JodaTime's `ReadableInstant` or `ReadablePartial`.

You need to convert it before providing it to the view.

```
DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(date.getTime());
request.setAttribute("myDate", dateTime);
```